# Did i get the the complexity right?

Tags: python, time-complexity

So, in the image I have the code and beside it has the time of each line. I think the   while has O(n) because it will repeat n times (I think the worst case is when enter the while and does all iteractions and the two first's "if" because in this way it will do more operations (there is another one where it doesnt need to do this to make the same number of operations but i consider this case)). The ifs will have 0(n-1) because they are inside the while and in the last loop they will not happen.The rest i think its O(1). Can someone confirm if this is corret?
'''

```
def find_eq(self,y):                              time
    w=self.r                                        1
    while w is not None:                            n
        if y < w.x:                                 n-1
            w=w.e                                   0
        elif y > w.x:                               n-1
            w=w.d                                   n-1
        else:                                       0
            return  w.x                             0
    return None                                     1
```

'''

Comment: It seems correct for me. But while I was searching for time complexities. I came upon this library. Thought you might try it out so I will give a link for you to check.
https://pypi.org/project/radon/

Comment: @Batselot Thx, i will check it!

Comment: It's actually impossible to say without more information. To be honest, this looks like a binary search, where w is some range and w.x is a dynamically recomputed midpoint. If this were the case, then it'd be O(log(n)), but it's impossible to say without knowing the type of items in the array and what self is, and what the structure of these .r, .e, .d, and .x members are. It really depends.

Comment: @JacobSteinebronn Yes, this is a binary search,where w is the root ( iniciallly, because we define r as the root ) and w.x is its value, w.e its the node in the left, and w.d is the node in the rigth.

Comment: In that case, the time complexity is `O(log(n))`, not linear.

Comment: But how can i get that value?